# Feit receptacle with USB ports trip GFCI

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, gfci

I replaced a standard dual 120V outlet at the end of a kitchen counter GFCI circuit with the Feit dual 120V with 2 USB Ports.  I taped over the outlet screws as I'm pushing it into a metal box and a tight fit.  Works fine before I push it in.  It pops the GFCI when fully installed, and GFCI will not reset.  Help

Comment: You've alluded to the likely problem. Maybe photos would help identify others.

Comment: The tape you wisely used  should show witness marks if it was punched through. Did you use backstabs and did you overstrip (leave bare wire sticking out)?  Backstabs are single use so if you must pull them out, now use the screws. We hate backstabs here.

Comment: No backstabs on this outlet.  I checked the tape for witness marks and in fact put another layer over everything metal as it's going into a metal box.  Same problem.  I did mention this is the last of two outlets on the circuit, the first being the GFCI.  Thanks for answering

Comment: I'm outbound for two weeks so the problem will have to wait.  Thanks for corresponding.  Next step is to take it out and try again, forget the USB capability, or take it back.  I can't say it's faulty can I if it works when out of the metal box.  I also can't switch to a plastic box in the space allotted.  Still looking for ideas.